# Getting memory leak in NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c

Im getting the same memory leak as I mentioned the link below.

[NSXMLParser Leaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598928/nsxmlparser-leaking).

Is it the real problem from the Apple developing side?

And in that link I saw the answer from Lee Armstrong as:

Apple have got back to me and this is a bug #6469143

Looks like they plan to fix for 4.0

Is there any documentation regarding to this problem???

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish.

Comment: Hello guys,I need a quick answer from you.I am waiting for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the thread you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598928/nsxmlparser-leaking/2115541#2115541), Apple has acknowledged this as a bug and it will be fixed in a forthcoming release of the iPhone OS.  So it looks like you're out of luck until then.  There is no documentation as to what's actually getting leaked, because the leak is inside Apple's code and we (obviously) don't have ready access to Apple's source code.

Comment: Thanks for your information.Does the leaks may leads to Application crash or any Exceptions??

Comment: can any one gimme reply for my question I posted as comment.

Comment: Leaking memory will not generate any exceptions, but it might generate a crash if you leak enough memory (many megabytes worth) to run out of heap space.  This `NSXMLParser` leak is unlikely to do that (unless you're creating thousands and thousands of `NSXMLParser` objects)

Answer (score 0):

NSXMLParser will leak if the URL you provided is not valid.

Comment: Seems to always leak with URL.
Workaround:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019240/memory-leak-using-nsxmlparser-in-nsconcretemaptable