# Memory Leak Mystery

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Greetings.  I'm almost finished with my first iPhone app, but have run into trouble with XML parsing.  Instruments reports that the instantiation line sparks a memory leak in my parseXML method, but I can't figure out why.  Here's the (entire) code for the method.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
-(void)parseXML:(NSString *)xHC {
BOOL success;
NSURL *xmlURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:hcXMLSource];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
success = [xmlParser parse];
[xmlParser release];
[xmlURL release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the link but this is a bug in the simulator.
It shows that there is a memory leak from the XmlParser when there isn't.

If you run the app through the device and track leaks it shouldn't find any.

I'll let you know if I find the link but I had this problem as well and this was the solution.

Comment: Found it! Look at the first answer of this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598928/nsxmlparser-leaking