# iPhone: memory leak on autoreleased object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, autorelease

I am using the XMLParser class, which contains an array with XMLElement objects. The XMLElement is being allocated using the autorelease operation. However, for some reason I'm getting a memory leak (using instruments) on this line:

```
self.currentElement = [[[XMLElement alloc] init] autorelease];
```

I'm also releasing the XMLParser object in the caller class. I've highlighted the "problematic" lines in the XMLParser source code below as comment.

I really tried everything to fix it, but unfortunately I do not understand why this is happening at all. Any help is appreciated!

Thank you very much!

```
// --- XMLElement

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface XMLElement : NSObject {
     NSDictionary *attributes;
     NSMutableArray *children;
     NSString *textValue;
     NSString *tagName;
     XMLElement *parentElement;
}

-(id) init;
-(void) addChild:(XMLElement*) child;

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *attributes;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *children;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *textValue;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *tagName;
@property(nonatomic, retain) XMLElement *parentElement;

@end


#import "XMLElement.h"


@implementation XMLElement

@synthesize attributes, children, textValue, parentElement, tagName;

-(id)init {
     if(self = [super init]) {
          children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     }
     return self;
}

-(void) addChild:(XMLElement*) child{
     [self.children addObject:child];
}

- (void)dealloc {
     [attributes release];
     [children release];
     [textValue release];
     [tagName release];
     [parentElement release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end





// --- XMLParser

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XMLElement.h"

@interface XMLParser : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate> {
     XMLElement *currentElement;
     XMLElement *currentParentElement;
     NSMutableString *currentElementValue;
}

- (BOOL)parseData: (NSData*) dataToParse;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
     attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;

@property (nonatomic, retain) XMLElement *currentParentElement;
@property (nonatomic, retain) XMLElement *currentElement;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *currentElementValue;

@end


#import "XMLParser.h"


@implementation XMLParser

@synthesize currentElementValue, currentElement, currentParentElement;

- (BOOL)parseData: (NSData*) dataToParse {

     NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:dataToParse];
     [parser setDelegate:self];
     BOOL success = [parser parse];
     [parser release];
     return success;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
     attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
     if(currentElement){
          self.currentParentElement = currentElement;
     }


     // ------------------------------------------------------------
     // Instruments is marking this line as source of the leak with 90%
     self.currentElement = [[[XMLElement alloc] init] autorelease];
     // --------

     currentElement.tagName = elementName;
     currentElement.attributes = attributeDict;
     currentElement.parentElement = self.currentParentElement;
     if(self.currentParentElement){
          [self.currentParentElement addChild:currentElement]; // and this one with 10%
     }

     self.currentElementValue = nil;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
     if(!currentElement) {
          return;
     }

     if(currentElementValue == nil)
          self.currentElementValue = [NSMutableString stringWithString:string];
     else
          [currentElementValue appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
     if(currentElement == nil){
          if( currentParentElement.parentElement){
               self.currentParentElement = currentParentElement.parentElement;
          }
     }else{
          currentElement.textValue = currentElementValue; 
          [currentElementValue release];
          currentElementValue = nil;
          self.currentParentElement = currentElement.parentElement;
          currentElement = nil;
     }
}

- (void)dealloc {
     [currentParentElement release];
     [currentElement release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

You must release `currentElement` in your `dealloc` method in XMLParser.

It's created as `autorelease` but then assigned to a `retain` property, so you are actually retaining it once (which is good).

UPDATE: you should do `self.currentElement = nil;` when you are done with it, not `currentElement = nil;`.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
self.currentElement = [[[XMLElement alloc] init] autorelease];
```

retains `currentElement` (because the property is declared with `retain`).

Later, in `parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:`, you do this:

```
currentElement = nil;
```

which causes the leak because you are not releasing `currentElement`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated it like you suggested, but I still get the memory leak. Here is the updated code:

Comment: - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
 //NSLog(@"Processing didEndElement: %@", elementName);
 if(currentElement == nil){
  if( currentParentElement.parentElement){
   self.currentParentElement = currentParentElement.parentElement;
  }
 }else{
  currentElement.textValue = currentElementValue; 
  [currentElementValue release];
  self.currentElementValue = nil;
  self.currentParentElement = currentElement.parentElement;
  self.currentElement = nil;
 }
}

Comment: @user480451: do you seriously expect anybody to be able to read that?  Edit the question to put the code in it.

Comment: :) yea you are absolutely right. i didn't find the "reply" button here... so i'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

From what I see on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598928/nsxmlparser-leaking), this is a documented apple bug.  I have experienced the same problem in some of my apps...

Answer (score 0):

Is your `XMLParser` being run on a background thread?  If so, you need to create an `NSAutoReleasePool` for that thread in order for your `[[[XMLElement alloc] init] autorelease]` call to work.

Answer (score 0):

HI guys.
the reason is just one simple thing,

instead of

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) XMLElement *parentElement;
```

must be

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) XMLElement *parentElement;
```

also you need delete `[parentElement release]` from `dealloc`

reason is that you are creating cyclic referances. parent to child and chils to parent

and when you are realesing parser object the elements still ocurrs in memory with pointer xount > 0