# iPhone memory leak when method returns object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, malloc, return

I'm developping on iOS 4 and I've got this method in my appDelegate. It is called from a couple of tableviews datasource delegates. Instruments gave me these (on device and simulator)
Malloc 512 bytes, Malloc 512 bytes, NSConcreteMapTable (Foundation). The Mallocs don't show any responsible library.

Here's the method returning the object:

```
- (NSXMLParser *) getXmlParserFrom:(NSString *)remoteFile andCacheToFile:(NSString *) fileName forceRefresh:(BOOL) doRefresh {  
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser;

    //FIRST TRY TO LOAD THE XML FROM CACHED FILE  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSString *xmlDocumentFromCache = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    if ( xmlDocumentFromCache && !doRefresh ) {  
        NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
    }  else {  
        NSURL *xmlFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:remoteFile];
        NSString *contentsOfRemoteFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:xmlFileURL];

        //CACHE THE FILE  
        BOOL cacheResult = [contentsOfRemoteFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlFileURL];
    }  
    [xmlDocumentFromCache release];

    return [xmlParser autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Dup of [NSXMLParser Leaking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598928/nsxmlparser-leaking). Basically, it's a bug (#6469143) in NSXMLParser. Should be fixed in an upcoming version of iOS. Check the answers to the linked question for workarounds. Also read ["NSXMLParser *rssParser is causing a memory leak"](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4910-nsxmlparser-rssparser-causing-memory-leak.html) on iPhon Dev SDK. Googling "NSConcreteMapTable NSXMLParser" will turn up other pages on the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this by using the method outlined in [this post](http://blog.filipekberg.se/2010/11/30/nsxmlparser-has-memory-leaks-in-ios-4/).

It's a workaround, but it works.

On another note, I have found that Instruments works reliably in Lion/Xcode 4.1 if you always run it on the device, as opposed to the simulator. On the simulator, it seems to have a devil of a time attaching to the process.